# About scaling the database in docker swarm

Tags: django, docker, docker-swarm

So I created a Docker Swarm with Django, Apache, and PostgreSQL all running in an overlay network called `internal_network`. When I scale Apache and Django services, it works perfectly fine, except for Django, I have to wait a little longer for it to do the migration. But when I scale the PostgreSQL service, Django just break, like first time go to my Django admin page okay then I reload the page Django printed out

```
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
```

If I reload again, Django admin back to normal again and this cycle keep looping when I reload the page.

I think Django seem to be conflicted about having 2 PostgreSQL task running on my swarm that it just won't work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just found out that in order to scale the database, I need to do more steps in order to do that. It's also dependent on the database technology and how it handle replicas and it's not simple as running a worker node or container

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your solution?